# How to set up webpack for Pug, React, and ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, pug-loader

I’m trying to make a website using React and ES6. I’m using Webpack to transpile my JS using Babel and it works fine. Now I need to know how to write my template in Pug (or HTML for that matter) and add it to the Webpack workflow. I want my build folder to have two files:

1. My `bundle.js`
2. My `index.html` file compiled from my `index.pug` file

An example `webpack.config.js` file would be helpful but what I really would like is just the general idea of how to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are few webpack plugins you need to install first to use pug template with webpack.

1. [htmlwebpack plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin)
2. [pug-loader](https://github.com/pugjs/pug-loader)

With htmlwebpack plugin you can specify your pug template file

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template : './index.pug',
      inject   : true
})
```

pug template file will be loaded by pug-loader.

```
    {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        loaders: [ 'pug-loader' ]
    },
```

A sample webpack config file can be like below -

```
const path              = require('path');
const webpack           = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const isTest = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test'

module.exports = {

  devtool: 'eval-source-map',

  entry: {
      app: [
          'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
          './src/app.jsx'
      ]
  },
  output: {
    path       : path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    pathinfo   : true,
    filename   : 'bundle.js',
    publicPath : '/'
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin("style.css", { allChunks:false }),
    isTest ? undefined : new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          template : './index.pug',
          inject   : true
    })
  ].filter(p => !!p),

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.json', '.js', '.jsx']
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test    : /\.jsx?$/,
            loader  : 'babel',
            exclude : /node_modules/,
            include : path.join(__dirname, 'src')
        },
        {
            test    : /\.scss?$/,
            loader  : ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader!autoprefixer-loader!sass-loader"),
            include : path.join(__dirname, 'sass')
        },
        {
            test    : /\.png$/,
            loader  : 'file'
        },
        {
            test    : /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
            loader  : 'file'
        },
        {
            test: /\.pug$/,
            include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
            loaders: [ 'pug-loader' ]
        },
        {
            include : /\.json$/,
            loaders : ["json-loader"]
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll try this. Thanks!

Comment: Great! It works! The HtmlWebpackPlugin was the missing piece :)

Comment: is there a way to generate pug file instead of html for output

Comment: upvoted! isnt express already rendering the pug files on its own

Comment: Also needed to install `pug` without which the `pug-loader` seems lost